# VB.NET How iterate through a BindingSource

Tags: vb.net, bindingsource

I have a BindingSource bound to a DataTable.

I use the BS Filter and would like to iterate the filtered dataset of the DataTable using the Bindingsource.

I know I can do a MoveFirst and the MoveNext and each time using the BS.Position get the correct row in the underlying DataTable.
But how do I know when the sets ends? I'm sure there must be such a property, but what is it?

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Sub BindDataGridView()    
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For count = 0 To EmployeeListBindingSource.Count - 1
        Dim RowIndex As Integer = dataGrdView1.Rows.Add()
        Dim row As DataRowView = DirectCast(EmployeeListBindingSource.Item(count), DataRowView)
        dataGrdView1.Rows(RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = row.Item(1).ToString
        dataGrdView1.Rows(RowIndex).Cells(2).Value = row.Item(0).ToString
    Next
End Sub
```

Declare a row as:

```
Dim row As DataRowView = DirectCast(EmployeeListBindingSource.Item(count), DataRowView)
```

Then, access columns like:

```
row.Item(1).ToString
```

Compare it with  `if CompareStr <> row.Item(1).ToString then`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

BindingSource has Count property